# Dialogflow: Add training phrases to existing intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a list with training phrases that I would like to import into Dialogflow.
I have tried formatting the phrases as a JSON (example: "hello_usersays_en.json"), but I get an error stating "invalid intent".

How can I import training phrases as JSON or any other way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to manually type the phrases in the Dialogflow console
OR
You can download the intent

[image]
and using a shell or python script of yours, add the phrases to the existing intent and then upload that intent back.

[image]